# "Backward" binomial sum $\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can we simplify the "backward" binomial sum
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk x^n?$$

The problem is well-known if we sum over $k$ instead of $n$, but how about the above one?

Comment: It is $$\frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}},$$ for $|x|<1.$

Comment: $$\begin{align} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^kz^n&=\sum_n (1+x)^nz^n\\&=\frac{1}{1-z(1+x)}\\&=\frac{1}{1-z}\frac1{1-\frac z{1-z}x}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{ (1-z)^{k+1}}x^k\end{align} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reindex the series with $m = n-k$

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty {n \choose k}x^n = \sum_{m=0}^\infty {m+k \choose k}x^{m+k} = x^k\sum_{m=0}^\infty {m+k \choose m}x^{m} $$

This is a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with $r = k+1$

$$= \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}}\cdot\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty {m+k \choose m}x^{m}(1-x)^{k+1}\right) = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)^{k+1}} \cdot (1)$$

hence the name "negative binomial" since as you described it sums "backwards" from what we're used to.